# How can we void the document using REST api

Tags: docusignapi

I have sent a document using REST API, Is there any possibility to void the same document using REST API?

Comment: 1. What do you think REST API is? 2. What do you mean by making a document void?

Comment: #1: Restful web services. #2: Voiding stops recipients from viewing or signing the document.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can VOID an envelope which has yet to reach a terminated state (i.e: Completed, Declined, Voided, Expired).

https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/RESTAPIGuide.htm#REST%20API%20References/Void%20Envelope.htm?Highlight=void